# Using NLTK library for concordance but it is not displaying in text widget

Tags: python, nltk

I wanted to find concordance for a specific word. I am getting output from concordance which is ok. The issue is when i want to insert that concordance to a text widget. It says nonetype of concordance variable.

My code

```
value = self.search_box.get().lower()
words = nltk.word_tokenize(file_contents)
texts = Text(words)
concordance = texts.concordance(value, lines=20)
self.text_widget.delete("1.0", "end")
self.text_widget.insert("1.0", f"\n\nConcordance of \"{value}\":\n", "bold")
self.text_widget.insert("1.0", concordance)
```

Output getting in terminal

```
India and the Islamic Republic of Pakistan . The two countries have a complex
thern India and most of modern-day Pakistan overlap with each other in terms o
inion of India and the Dominion of Pakistan . The partitioning of the former B
 Radcliffe Line to reach India and Pakistan , respectively . [ 1 ] In 1950 , I
y . Shortly afterwards , in 1956 , Pakistan emerged as an Islamic republic wit
```

this output is showing it concordance automatically i am not using print statement.
but my text widget is not accepting it. It there an alternative way to solve this issue.
Please help me out to resolve the issue.